# using csurf with session in express

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, csrf, express-session

I'm writing a single page application with `MEAN stack`, and using `express-session` with `redis` for session management.

I want to use scrf token in my client's cookies.

the problem is when I add `csurf` middleware, it set a session with name `csrfSecret` in redis, but how can I send it in cookie to client?

middlewares :

```
 app.use(csrf({}));

 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.cookie('csrf-token', req.csrfToken());
     return next();
 });
```

and `csrf-token` is sending to client but it don't do anything.and I receive 403 error from module.

thank you for any answer or idea.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a csrf cookie in the client you have to use the following:

```
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true })
```

This will create a token in the client. If you do not pass any options to the csrf function it will use `req.session`. If you want to save the cookie client-side, remember that you will need to use `cookie-parser` module.

You can find more information in the github link to the project: https://github.com/expressjs/csurf

Comment: cookie options can be found in https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf#cookie